# Formula to identify the 1st and 2nd currency in a currency pair e.g. USD/CAD

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I have a column A where it lists all kinds of **Currency Pairs**,

I have a column B whose header says, **Currency**. This lists the individual currency, either the 1st or the 2nd currency from the Currency Pair column.

```
**Currency Pairs**  **Currency**   **Trade Amount**   **Rate**   **Notional**  
USD/CAD                  CAD          100               1.3        100/1.3

GBP/USD                  GBP          200               1.3        200*1.3
```

The Notional column is where I need to construct an excel formula. This formula varies depending on whether the Currency is the same as the 1st or 2nd currency in the Currency Pair. In the first e.g., CAD is the same as the 2nd currency of the USD/CAD currency pair.

- If the currency is the same as the 1st currency in the currency pair, I need to multiply the Trade Amount by the Rate.
- If the currency is the same as the 2nd currency in the currency pair, I need to divide the Trade Amount by the Rate.

My question is whether there is an excel formula to calculate the notional per the 2 variation above?

Answer (score 0):

You can put the following formula in Notional Column and drag it down.

```
=IF(B2=LEFT(A2,LEN(A2)-SEARCH("/",A2,1)),C2*D2,IF(B2=MID(A2,SEARCH("/",A2,1)+1,LEN(A2)-SEARCH("/",A2,1)),C2/D2,"Invalid"))
```

Usually a simpler formula shall also work as the Currency Abbreviations are usually 3 Characters long. Still this formula uses the delimiter / to separate the currency abbreviations and compare. It also adds a third condition just in case there's an error that the Currency is none of the two from the pair. This can be removed if not required.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try this formula:

```
=ROUND(C2*D2^(1-2*(FIND(TRIM(B2),TRIM(A2))>1)),2)
```

[image]

Expression `(1-2*(FIND(TRIM(B2),TRIM(A2))>1))` will be 
either `1`  or `-1`.

Answer (score 0):

I do this at work actually. The way we handle it is by listing each pair combo - For example, USDCAD is one entry, and CADUSD is another entry. USDCAD = 1/CADUSD

Answer (score 0):

A simple formula will handle this:

```
 =IF(LEFT(A2,3)=B2,C2*D2,C2/D2)
```

And even with error checking, it's short:

```
=IF(LEFT(A2,3)=B2,C2*D2,IF(RIGHT(A2,3)=B2,C2/D2,"Error")
```

[image]